# SUM in a recursive procedure

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I have a problem doing some recursive procedure.
Here is the script I made which works well (except the sum I'm gonna explain later):

```
;WITH RESULT (MOTHER, CHILD, QUANTITY) as
(
    select Mother, Child, CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), Quantity) as Quantity 
    from bilangammestest 

    union all 

    select M.mother, R.Child, CONVERT(Numeric(10,0), M.quantity * R.Quantity) as Quantity 
    from Result R 
    INNER JOIN bilangammestest M ON M.Child = R.Mother
)

select * from result
where mother not in (select child from bilangammestest)
```

Here are the data I have on my table `Bilangammestest`:

```
Z A 1    
Z Y 1    
A B 2    
Y B 2    
B C 3
```

Here are the result I get :

```
Z A 1    
Z Y 1    
Z C 6    
Z C 6    
Z B 2    
Z B 2
```

Here is the final result I want:

```
Z A 1    
Z Y 1    
Z C 12    
Z B 4
```

I tried to do a `sum` but I couldn't do it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last query should be:

```
select MOTHER, CHILD, sum(quantity) quantity
from result
where mother not in (select child from bilangammestest )
group by MOTHER, CHILD
```

Comment: Thank you ! :)
Is it possible to do un apdate doing this technique. I mean is it possible to use these quantities to update a table ?

Comment: @XXX Yes, you can use these results to update another table, or insert them somewhere else. I can't tell you the exact query to do so without more information though. You might want to post the update part as a new question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

Use `group by`

```
SELECT firstcolname, secondcolname, sum(thircolname) GROUP BY firstcolname, secondcolname
```